# Failed using `replace` directive in gcp cloudbuild

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm trying to build my go application using `serverless framework` in cloudbuild.

Here's my project structure

```
/api
   /giam
      go.mod
      API.go
   /other_folders...
/util
   go.mod
   util.go
```

Here's my build steps:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
- name: 'softinstigate/serverless'
  args: ['deploy', '-v']
  dir: 'api/giam'
  env: ['PROJECT_ROOT=${REPO_NAME}', 'GO111MODULE=on']
```

and here's my `go.mod` in `api/giam`

```
module mybackend

require bitbucket.org/myusername/mybackend/util v0.0.0

replace bitbucket.org/myusername/mybackend/util => /workspace/util
```

and I confirmed that I have a `go.mod` in my `util` folder.

and here's the content

```
module util

require cloud.google.com/go v0.37.1
```

#### The error

I got this error while running the cloudbuild..

```
{"ResourceType":"cloudfunctions.v1beta2.function","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"Build failed: go: parsing util/go.mod: open /workspace/util/go.mod: no such file or directory\ngo: error loading module requirements\n"}
```

if I got this right, the error is that it cannot find the `/workspace/util/go.mod`

I tried `ls` in the cloudbuild, specifically in `/workspace/util` and I found the `go.mod` file.

I'm pretty stuck here.. I don't know what to do next..

Comment: try `/workspace/util` => `../../util`

Comment: @beiping96 I tried that but the folder became `/util/go.mod` I guess this is because of the `PROJECT_ROOT=${REPO_NAME}` env in the cloudbuild config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using `vendor` and omitting `go.mod` and `go.sum` in serverless package (by using package.exclude).

Here's my updated `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  dir: 'api/giam'
  args: ['mod', 'edit', '-replace', 'bitbucket.org/myusername/mybackend/util=/workspace/util']
  env: ['GOPATH=/src', 'GO111MODULE=on']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  dir: 'api/giam'
  args: ['mod', 'vendor']
  env: ['GOPATH=/src', 'GO111MODULE=on']
- name: 'softinstigate/serverless'
  args: ['deploy', '-v']
  dir: 'api/giam'
  env: ['GOPATH=/src', 'GO111MODULE=on']
```

and my `go.mod`:

```
module mybackend

require (
    bitbucket.org/myusername/mybackend/util v0.0.0
    google.golang.org/api v0.2.1-0.20190318183801-2dc3ad4d67ba
)

replace bitbucket.org/myusername/mybackend/util => ../../util
```

as per github issue in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/issues/743,
it says that you need to exclude go.mod and go.sum in the deployment, otherwise the vendor won't be used. That's why in `serverless.yml` I use:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - vendor/**
    - '*.go'
```